# Atomikos Error in init(): Couldn't get lock for /var/lib/tomcat6/./tm.out

Tags: java, spring, ubuntu, tomcat6, atomikos

I need help with a project I'm working on. It's a web server built with Java spring. I use Tomcat 6 as web server.
I switched from MyEclipse For Spring to Eclipse EE and I cannot deploy my web server anymore on my Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit machine.

The exception I'm getting is the following:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'atomikosTransactionManager' defined in class path resource [GestioneOneriServlet-dao-context.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'transactionTimeout' threw exception; nested exception is com.atomikos.icatch.SysException: Error in init(): Couldn't get lock for /var/lib/tomcat6/./tm.out
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3972)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4467)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1251)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:612)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServlet.java:136)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:558)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested    PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'transactionTimeout' threw exception; nested exception is com.atomikos.icatch.SysException: Error in init(): Couldn't get lock for /var/lib/tomcat6/./tm.out
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:102)
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
... 33 more
```

My JTA.properties is as following:

```
com.atomikos.icatch.service=com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceFactory
com.atomikos.icatch.console_file_name = tm.out
com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_name = tmlog
com.atomikos.icatch.tm_unique_name = myeclipseforspring
com.atomikos.icatch.serial_jta_transactions=false
com.atomikos.icatch.automatic_resource_registration=true
com.atomikos.icatch.max_actives=15000
com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout=3600000
com.atomikos.icatch.enable_logging=false
com.atomikos.icatch.console_log_level=WARN
#com.atomikos.icatch.output_dir=/home/atomikos-sw-tmp/
#com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_dir=/home/atomikos-sw-tmp/
```

Last two properties are commented as one of the many trials I've done to resolve this error.

My servlet-dao-context.xml is:

```
<!-- Using Atomikos Transaction Manager -->
    <bean class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager" destroy-method="close" id="atomikosTransactionManager" init-method="init">
        <property name="forceShutdown" value="true"/>
        <property name="startupTransactionService" value="true"/>
        <property name="transactionTimeout" value="60"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp" id="atomikosUserTransaction"/>
    <!-- Configure the Spring framework to use JTA transactions from Atomikos -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager"/>
        <property name="userTransaction" ref="atomikosUserTransaction"/>
        <property name="transactionSynchronizationName" value="SYNCHRONIZATION_ON_ACTUAL_TRANSACTION"/>
    </bean>
```

I have no idea on how to make this work. I don't understand why it searches for the file tm.out in the path /var/lib/tomcat6/./tm.out. What does that "/./" stand for?

Please help.
Andrea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had the same issue. It seems like tomcat is not installing with the correct permissions or I have missed something in the atomikos configuration.

On my installation /var/lib/tomcat6 is permissioned as 'root' whereas all of the other sub-directories are 'tomcat6'. As tomcat runs as user tomcat6, it cannot create the file.

I changed the owner of /var/lib/tomcat6 directory to tomcat6 and all works fine with no issue.
I assume that atomikos is expecting something to give it a sub directory of the tomcat directory, but this is set to '.' (which means the current directory on its own or the present directory if it forms part of a path, like '..' means the parent directory).
Hence it is actually $TOMCAT_HOME/{atomikos-dir}/tm.out

If you can find out where to change '.' to something better, then this would avoid the directory permissions issue (and if you do I would suggest changing it back at a later stage!)

Comment: See http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/JtaProperties setup, you will see there are settings for the log directories that can be changed. By default it uses the current directory, so ensure the property file is created and the location given.

Comment: Thank you! The problem was the one you described... damned permissions!!